# why does this send the same image?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am working on a Discord command to grab an image from Unsplash's random image generator. Right now I have the image pulled from https://source.unsplash.com/random. As you can see, it pulls a random Unsplash image every time you go to the URL. But whenever I run this simple Discord command, it sends the same image. Might it be a Discord cache or is there something I'm doing wrong here?

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: "image",
    aliases: ["random", "img"],
    category: "fun",
    description: "Sends an epic image from unsplash",
    run: async (client, message, args) => {

        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("RANDOM")
            .setImage('https://source.unsplash.com/random/')
            .setTitle(`From Unsplash`)
            .setURL(`https://unsplash.com/`);

        message.channel.send(embed);
        console.log("image run")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that you will need to change the URL a little, each time that you are calling the api

My workaround is supplying a query parameter..

```js
// Get a hook function
const {useState} = React;

const Example = ({title}) => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [image, setImage] = useState('https://source.unsplash.com/random');
  
  const getImage = () => {
    
    ///setImage('')
      setTimeout(() => {
      setImage('https://source.unsplash.com/random?count'+ Date.now())
      }, 1000)
    
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => getImage()}>
        Click to change the image
      </button>
      <img src={image} width='400px' height='400px' />
    </div>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example title="Example using Hooks:" />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```